# ADB Debugging on LG Watch R

Tags: adb, lg

I got a LG Watch R for a programming project. First, I had a Gear Live that was now replaced. When I follow the guides step by step, I never get the "authorize this computer" like I did with Gear Live. My machine runs on Windows 7. My steps were:

1. Setup LG Watch R with my Note 3
2. Dev Mode enabled, enabled ADB Debugging
3. Plugged the Charging Station in my PC (got detected as "Android Composite ADB Interface" with Samsung as Company
4. Normally the popup should appear on my Smartphone asking me to authorize the machine
5. In the CMD, `adb devices` does return unauthorized

In the device manager, the Watch R is recognized as "Android Composite ADB Interface" from Samsung. I have tried [an answer to "ADB doesn't recognize Samsung Gear Live or LG G watch" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716409/2821954), but it doesn't change much as it is already recognized as ADB Composite.

I'd be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It turns out that the watch has to be connected to an Android phone running the Android Wear app; then the "authorize" dialog will appear on the Android phone. After you authorize you can unpair the phone.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but i tried that too - the authorize dialog didnt appear - tried it on my laptop as well. When resetting my Note 3 i get the dialog in an instant.